# В каком виде хранить текст книги в БД, и какую БД (реляционную/не реляционную) для этого лучше использовать?

Tags: база-данных, текст, хранение-данных

Делаю некоммерческий пэт-проект, просто для души. Выглядеть он будет как сайт-читалка для конкретной книги, где можно будет делать сноски и пояснения к различным местам в тексте. Из необходимого функционала:

1. ссылки, которые генерируются на конкретное место в тексте
2. возможность делать сноски **на абзац**, **на небольшую последовательность слов**, **на одно слово**
3. Возможность разделять текст на главы и страницы на фронте

Здесь и появляются несколько вопросов:

1. Как хранить текст самого произведения (построчно, побуквенно, по главам), может быть нужна какая-то многоуровневая кластеризация?
2. Как хранить сноски, а именно привязку к конкретному месту в тексте, к слову или абзацу? А из всего этого вытекает:
3. Какую БД под такое подобрать?

Покопался немного, но только в голову не приходит ничего кроме как к каждому слову сгенерировать хэш и потом как-то по хэшу/набору таких хэшей искать последовательность слов, а после уже отрисовывать блок-выделение для текста, к которому уже будут крепиться сноски. Еще читал, что вроде mongoDB под такое можно взять, но как хранить данные всё же не ясно. Может быть у кого-то был подобный опыт или просто задача покажется интересной с архитектурной точки зрения и будет не лень будет подкинуть мне почву для размышлений, какую-нибудь статью или книгу.

Примерная визуализация страницы со сноской:
[image: pic]

Comment: по сноске 2 числа храни - номер начала и конца выделения

Comment: вместо хешей используй индекс полнотекстового поиска и базу с поддержкой такого индекса используй)

Comment: ну возможно elasticsearch вам поможет как с поиском внутри текста, так и с его хранением

Comment: *Как хранить текст самого произведения* Как единый поток, со статическим форматированием, если оно присутствует. *Как хранить сноски, а именно привязку к конкретному месту в тексте, к слову или абзацу?* Любое дополнение хранится отдельно - две позиционные ссылки (как смещение, начало и конец привязки), тип дополнения (ссылка, сноска, элемент форматирования) и формализованный код значения (смещение ссылки, текст сноски, форматные данные - начало главы, начало подзаголовка и пр.). *Какую БД под такое подобрать?* Да без разницы, всё равно основная работа - это работа по отображению на клиенте.

Comment: Текст может редактироваться или всё readonly? Т. е. один раз книгу внесли и дальше только комментарии добавляем? Деление на главы обычно делает автор текста, а не "на фронте".

Comment: @Qwertiy Текст не должен редактироваться. Он будет загружен единожды. Это уже старая книга, которую вряд ли кто-то будет править и дополнять. Я спрашивал о разделении в контексте хранения информации и удобства ее представления в БД и на фронте

Comment: @Akina Т.е. по вашему мнению будет не важно в какой БД хранить текст? Не будет ли тому же Postgres больно вытаскивать такой объем текста, чтобы просто пролистать до нужной страницы или абзаца? Хотя это уже необходимо тестировать на модели...

Comment: *Т.е. по вашему мнению будет не важно в какой БД хранить текст?* Ну почему? любые крайности следует отбросить. А из средних устроит любой выбор. Постгресс? пусть будет он, не вижу ни особых плюсов, ни столь же особых минусов. Равно как и не вижу особого смысла хранить текст в БД - пусть себе валяется в файловой системе, оттуда клиенту его и получать проще. А СУБД будет поставлять в него разметки, пометки и украсявки. А клиент всё это будет отрисовывать. Да, ничто не мешает в той же таблице держать ещё и сведения о разделении - да хоть бы и смещения начал/концов абзацев.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Лучше всего разбить по абзацам, так как в дальнейшем наверняка придется делать пагинацию. И грузить большое количество текста одним запросом будет трудно.
2. Лучше всего прямо в тексте и уже при выводе его обрабатывать.
   Пример: `(%% "СЛОВО ИЛИ АБЗАЦ" : "ТЕКСТ ЕГО СНОСКИ" : "ЦВЕТ ЕГО СНОСКИ" %%)`
   В данном случае "(%%" , "%%)" и ":" - просто разделители, которые при выводе текста ты сможешь обработать уже на клиентской стороне.
3. Можно присмотреться к Postgres или к MongoDB

Comment: Не пострадает ли скорость "доставания" если всё хранить в одной сущности текста/абзаца? И что думаете насчет индексов Elasticsearch? Если использовать их, то как лучше хранить текст? Оставить разбитым по абзацам или же свалить всё в кучу и понадеяться на скорость и быстроту работы по индексам?

Comment: На счет скорости и оптимизации получения текстов я бы говорил уже после того как решил бы в каком формате мне нужны будут данные. То есть из идея для размышления к примеру - заранее разделить текст на страницы для всех вариантов вывода( для каждого экрана), и возможно тогда даже не хранить весь текст в базе, а отдельными файлами, что в теории может увеличить скорость чтения. Но однозначно можно сказать что хранить весь текст одним куском - плохая идея.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю хранить текст не в базе, а в файле: чтение с диска будет быстрее, меньшая нагрузка на базу, проще править метки, исходный текст в полной сохранности.
В базе хранить лишь инструкции для обработки текста.
То есть производится чтение с диска допустим с первого по сотый байт. Делается запрос в базу select marks from table where name=name and position>first_byte and position<last_byte
Далее обрабатываем результаты и выводим их. Результаты предпочтительнее обрабатывать javascript'ом чтобы снизить нагрузку на сервер.